# Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/email

Tags: android, android-resources

I got this error. Would somebody know how to fix it. All i had written

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_emailid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Comment: Did you put an image with the name `email` inside the `drawable` folder?

Comment: Do i have to put an image because its consists only text? If i have to put then where in the drawable folder?

Comment: `... its consists only text?` **NO**. `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email"` Means that you put an **image** on the left of the EditText character area. Therefore, it's **not text**. `... where in the drawable folder?` In the folder named "drawable".